# clarifying the characteristic function

Tags: probability-theory

From my notes:

**Definition 106**: Define the characteristic function of a random variable $X$ or its culmulative distribution function $F_x$ to be the complex-valued function on $t \in \mathbb{R}$ $$ \varphi_X(t)=E[e^{itX}]=\int e^{itx}dF=E[\cos(tX)]+iE[\sin(tX)]$$

I don't understand what is $dF$ inside of the intergration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$F$  is the cumulative distribution function(cdf) of $X$.

You would see different definition of the expectation when the cdf or the density function $f_X$ is known
$$E[g(X)]=\int_{\mathbb{R}}{g(x)f_X(x)dx}$$

or you replace $f_X$ by $F$ using $$dF(x)=f_X(x)dx$$
$$E[g(X)]=\int_{\mathbb{R}}{g(x)dF(x)}$$

Comment: spelling, diction

Comment: Sorry, is the bounds of integration from 0 to 1 then? because $0 \leq F(x) \leq1$

Comment: No, the bounds of integration are in the domain of F, not its range.